Can someone explain the use of the rate_limiting policy in the Tail Sampling Processor in Open telemetry collector?
The documentation gives a very naive idea of the rate_limiting parameter here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/tailsamplingprocessor/README.md
Can someone give a detailed explanation of this policy along with a use case?
I have already raised a github issue for the same: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/35419
